# ios background task notification for BLE devices

Tags: sdk, background, bluetooth, notifications, iso

I'm developing a "background task enabled" app that connects to a BLE (bluetooth low energy) device. The user opens the app and connects to the BLE while the app is in the foreground. Once the app goes to the background it will keep communication open with the device (if in range) and be alert of any information received from such device. Now my question is how do I handle or even notice that data is coming from the device? It seems that right now my notifications are queued and are only shown when I manually bring the app to the foreground.

Thanks,

Andres N.

Comment: Did you figure this out @Andres?  I too am trying to learn the limitations of BLE in regards to background mode and inactive mode.  Trying to avoid a mandatory sync 'step' if device is always in range.