# Swift Notification based on BLE value when app it out of focus

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, usernotifications

I'm working on an iPhone app to control some custom BLE hardware.  I am able to talk to my device and generate all required controls, but my problem now comes with setting up UserNotifications.

Part of the functionality of this device is to alert the user if one of the BLE characteristic values gets outside of a certain range.  When the app is in focus, I am able to do this via UIAlerts.  I have played with UserNotifications and I can trigger a notification while the app is focused so that the notification will appear after a specific interval.  My issue is trying to generate a UserNotification based on data that's coming over a BLE connection in an app that's not focused.

I can tell via LED's on my hardware that the BLE connection is being maintained even while I'm out of focus/locked.  Is there a way to evaluate data from a background BLE connection and create a UserNotification based on it?

I found [This Question on StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050039/ios-background-task-notification-for-ble-devices) asking basically the same thing, but I'm hoping that several years later there may be more answers out there.

Cheers,

Roger

Comment: How does your peripheral notify your app that the data has changed?  Is it using a BLE Notify?  If so, then you should be able to check the attribute and post a local notification as long as you have set up your app for background operation

Comment: You should edit your question to show the relevant code where you receive the updated data and try and post a local notification

Comment: Thanks Paul.  To answer your question about how I'm getting information: my peripheral will update the characteristic value whenever it changes by more than a few counts.  My app is set to notify on value changes and then I get the new value via the 'didUpdateValue' callback.  This is all working currently and I can get new information while my app is open.  I think that you probably steered me in the right direction when you said "as long as you have set up your app for background operation" I'm new to IOS development and I think my next step is to research background operation.    Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Paulw11 above mentioned the app being set up for background operation, which I was not aware of (I'm really new to IOS, I'm more of a low-level firmware guy).

It was just a matter of setting up Xcode background mode to let this run in the background, now I can alert the user regardless of whether the app is Active or Background.